# which java dir to add to path or set java_home?

Tags: java, windows, scalar

im attempting to set up my pc for programming in scala, therefore I need to add java to my path.

Now, I have downloaded Java, and ensured that it is te correct version 1.8.0_261.

I can find tutorials that say that I should go in my path variable and add my java dir to there, but I can also find ones that say that I should make a java_home variable, and set it to my java. Which one of these is true?

Also in tutorials, the directory that people usually have for java is something like:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin
```

In my case, my java seems to be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, why is my folder not called jdk? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA\_HOME or PATH or BOTH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246552/java-home-or-path-or-both)

Comment: partially, my question also has a part about the jdk-folder, and is specific for setting up for scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how Oracle set it up, god knows why. Use  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin`, you can go ahead and remove the javapath from your PATH and it will still work. You have done nothing wrong.

Comment: ````C:\Program Files\Scala```` for Scala.