# problem with Java 8 in Amazon linux 1 vs Amazon linux 2

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, sh, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I'm running into a problem when migrate to run my Springboot app from Amazon linux 1 to Amazon linux 2. I'm using **run** file with **select the Java version** by **JAVA_HOME**:

- Amazon linux 1: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
- Amazon linux 2: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/bin/java

Every thing work normal in Amazon linux 1 but in Amazon linux 2, I got the **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** error. What really confuse me is that when I change the **whole java version of the instance** (attached image) then everything is running ok again.

I'm guessing the problem is how I point to the java jre but I can't figure it out. Can somebody please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Edit 1**: The sh file i use to run:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1

ulimit -n 10240

#For Java Classpath
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/bin/java
JAVA_BIN=$JAVA_HOME/bin/
export JAVA_HOME

EXTERNAL_HOME=external
EXTERNAL_RESOURCE=$EXTERNAL_HOME/resources

export SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=application
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=$EXTERNAL_RESOURCE/
export LOG_DIR=$EXTERNAL_HOME/logs
export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
cd $EXTERNAL_HOME
echo $SPRING_CONFIG_NAME
echo $SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION
echo $LOG_DIR
#exec nice -n 20 java -server -Xmx512M -Xms256M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar external-0.0.1.jar
#exec nice -n 20 java -server -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -jar external-0.0.1.jar
exec nice -n 20 java -server -Xmx512M -Xms256M -Dlogging.config=file:$EXTERNAL_RESOURCE/log4j2.properties \

 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar external-0.0.1.jar
```

Comment: How are you running your Spring Boot application? Via tomcat?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Right now I run it by sh file using command: sudo sh run

Comment: So whatever script you are running, may be that is reading Java from wrong location. Can you provide the script which you are using to run the program.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri I add it, please check it

Comment: Okay I suspect few things here. Firstly does `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/bin/java` this path contains `/bin` directory and that `bin` directory contains Java executables? Secondly, in the `exec` command append `$JAVA_BIN` ahead of `java` so that it will read Java from correct path - something like this `exec nice -n 20 $JAVA_BIN/java -server ...`.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri First: Yes, it contain the Java executables file. Second: I believe the export JAVA_HOME will do the trick so no need for the $JAVA_BIN. I run this normaly on Amazon linux 1

Comment: Reason it is working in Amazon linux 1 because it might be having only one Java installed there. In Amazon linux 2 you have multiple Java installed. And to execute `java` command, `JAVA_HOME` is not required. `java` reads from `PATH` variable. So exporting `JAVA_HOME` doesn't makes any sense as such. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246552/java-home-or-path-or-both/45246656

Comment: So here what mandatory is to check what `PATH` variable is pointing to. If it is pointing to another JVM than which you require, then as I said, you need to append `path to bin` to execute that particular java.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri I will try like you said. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri You are right sir. After add the PATH then it work again. And in Amazon linux 1, my coworker had change the java version of instance into Java 8 lead to I believe that my sh run file was right. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason it might be working in `Amazon linux 1` is it might be having only one Java installed there (or `PATH` is pointing to correct Java version). In `Amazon linux 2` you have multiple Java installed. And to execute java command, `JAVA_HOME` is not required. `java` command reads executable from `PATH` variable. So exporting `JAVA_HOME` doesn't makes any sense as such. Check this - [JAVA_HOME or PATH or BOTH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246552/java-home-or-path-or-both/45246656)

So here what mandatory is to check what `PATH` variable is pointing to. If it is pointing to another `JVM` than which you require, then you need to append `path to bin` to execute that particular `java`, something like this - `exec nice -n 20 $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server ...`.

Also as per my personal opinion, there is no need to export any variable from `script` unless you need that variable in another `script` which might be executed after the one which is exporting the variable. If you want to use that variable in single `script` only, then just use it without exporting it.